# What are switches activated by a closet door called?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, closet

My father-in-law set up all of his closet lights to turn on and off when the door opens. He used a switch that was apparently designed for that purpose, with a largish contact switch that turned on when pressed.

I'd buy some of these for my house, but I don't know what to call this item, so I can't find it.

Comment: Shopping questions are explicitly OT, but I'll edit this to something more appropriate.

Comment: Adding a photo may also help get better answers.

Comment: I can't add a photo, I don't have the item. My father-in-law lived in a different state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two styles that I've seen:

"Automatic closet lights" that mount at the top of the door and include the light socket.
[image: automatic closet light]

And "push button door switches" that are mounted in the door jamb and connect to a hardwired light fixture.

[image: push button door switch]

Comment: Micro switches with rollers on the end of the contact arm are used, but you have to add your own enclosure