# How can I have a light turn on when a pocket door is opened?

Tags: electrical, lighting, doors, interior

I'm building a new home with quite a few pocket doors and would like to know if there is a way for the pantry and utility room lights to come on when the pocket door slides open.

Comment: This [question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/25644/33) might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some very sophisticated kits that actually use a motion sensor on the slider.  These are very very expensive and if you have a problem down the road you are taking out a bunch of drywall.  You can go this route.

However a pantry and utility room are closed off smaller spaces.  I would just put an [occupancy sensor](http://www.lowes.com/pd_245717-539-MS-OPS2H-WH_0__?productId=3526624&Ntt=occupancy%20sensors&pl=1&currentURL=?Ntt=occupancy%2bsensors&facetInfo=) near the door in each room.  This will turn the lights on when you open and walk in.

Answer (score 1):

Install a normally open switch that closes when the door no longer presses on it as it starts to open.  If you want to avoid the NEC hassle use a 12 VAC system.

Comment: I'm fairly sure 12 VAC systems are covered by NEC.

Comment: "NEC hassle" means a permit and inspection?